# Overhead in creating an empty array?

Tags: java, performance

In order convert a List to an array, you need an empty array like following:

```
List<Foo> fooList;
Foo[] foos = fooList.toArray(new Foo[0]);
```

I happen to use this code snippet a lot, so instead of creating an empty array every time, I decided to create a static empty array, and use it each time. e.g.

```
private static Foo[] EMPTY_FOOS = new Foo[0];

List<Foo> fooList;
Foo[] foos = fooList.toArray(EMPTY_FOOS);
```

Is this worth it or are we looking at a difference of 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001ms?

Comment: It can be worth it.  This is what profiling is for.  Only you can determine what is a bottleneck in your own code.

Comment: Bit optimization is root of problems.

Comment: @Saeed, nonsense.  The problem is optimizations before any observation of an actual problem.

Comment: Is there a specific reason Why you don't use the parameter less toArray() function?

Comment: @Julien May Because you'd need to cast each element in the array then.

Comment: @KirkWoll, If another developer use this static field it can be a devil.

Comment: @JulienMay probably because of type-safety and casts/warnings

Comment: @Saeed, what on earth are you talking about?  An empty array is immutable and categorically safe to use in any situation (multi-threading, etc.)  (make it final if you don't want the field modified)

Comment: @KirkWoll, e.g EMPTY_FOOS = null

Comment: @Saeed, obviously make the field `final` then.  That is hardly material to the discussion.

Comment: @KirkWoll, I'm not java guy, but If it was .net and somebody uses reflection, I can show you problems, or if the class has static constructors,... but in all, we can apply bit optimization, while they aren't bottleneck in our application, sure this (empty array init) can't be bottleneck in normal applications (except you program for NASA or so), and we shouldn't do such an optimizations. which reduces code safety and readability.

Comment: @Saeed, *deeply* ironic you mention .net since they have `Type.EmptyTypes` to address **precisely** this concern.  Honestly, suggesting code is vulnerable because people can hack at the class model via reflection is patently ridiculous.

Comment: @Kirk, I'm not saying .net is good or bad, I'm saying there are lots of potential issues (known or unknown), ok man, you do your bit optimization, I'll remove them in refactor :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually I believe this is the best performing version:

```
fooList.toArray(new Foo[fooList.size()]);
```

This way `toArray()` always has the exact array and no extra arrays are created. IntelliJ suggests such a refactoring out of the box.

Comment: Excellent point, +1. If you don't do this, it will allocate more arrays "under the hood" anyways.

Comment: Or just don't use Java's "array" objects at all directly? (ArrayList, etc, use them internally.) They are really outcasts in the Java Collection framework.

Comment: If you pass an array of anything less than the size of the collection (including 0)., it will create exactly one more array (not "arrays") of exactly the correct number of elements.  However, it does use reflection to do that, so your way is still preferable.

Answer (score 2):

On my computer, creating 100,000,000 `Object[0]` arrays takes 2.9 seconds. If you are creating a million arrays per second, or even 100,000, it might make a measurable difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would make more sense to question why you need to convert arrays to Lists and vice versa in the first place. You'll be better off sticking with the Collection classes if you can and avoiding the use of arrays as they are more error prone that using Collection classes.

If you use that snippet of code 'a lot' then write a method that you can reuse, but in order to determine what effort you should invest in optimizing this code, you need to profile it and see what the overhead is in relation to your other code and how often this code is actually used at runtime.

As Knuth said: "premature optimization is the root of all evil" :-)